# Ubuntu 20.04.3 hangs on boot after upgrade to 5.13 kernel

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, intel-graphics

Following the recent upgrade to kernel 5.13.0-28-generic my system still cannot boot without 'nomodeset'. I have included the output from journalctl in hopes somebody can help me. I'm using the onboard Intel WiFi and graphics hardware. My system has the iwlwifi problem which I work around with

sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak

as found here:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13

Below is the boot log for kernel 5.13.0-28-generic in the area where things first appear to go wrong. Note the soft lockup of CPU#14

journalctl -k -b -1

```
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.25
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: pstore: Registered efi as persistent store backend
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop0: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 113536
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop2: detected capacity change from 0 to 634288
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop3: detected capacity change from 0 to 605624
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: checking generic (4000000000 300000) vs hw (6000000000 1000000)
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: checking generic (4000000000 300000) vs hw (4000000000 10000000)
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 448512
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 133552
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_02.bin (v2.2)
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: loop6: detected capacity change from 0 to 88616
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Feb 04 10:59:49 europa kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x7193, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047df60
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 63.c04f3485.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x8045CF40 | umac branchlink2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000007 | umac data1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00200808 | umac data2
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000003F | umac major
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xC04F3485 | umac minor
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000111FE | frame pointer
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xC0887F3C | stack pointer
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00007193 | IML/ROM data1
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Fseq Registers:
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00440003 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
Feb 04 10:59:50 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
Feb 04 10:59:51 europa kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 27s! [systemd-udevd:590]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: Modules linked in: snd_compress ac97_bus kvm_intel(+) snd_pcm_dmaengine iwlmvm snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acp>
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ip6table_filter parport_pc ip6_tables ppdev iptable_filter lp bpfilter drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 raid10 raid456 async>
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: CPU: 14 PID: 590 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./Z590 Steel Legend WiFi 6E, BIOS P1.80 07/22/2021
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RIP: 0010:skl_ddb_allocation_overlaps+0x25/0x50 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: Code: 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 85 d2 7e 33 44 8d 42 ff 31 c0 39 c1 74 1b 0f b7 54 86 02 66 39 17 73 11 0f b7 57 02>
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb4d340fbf6d8 EFLAGS: 00000297
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RDX: 0000000000000800 RSI: ffffb4d340fbf718 RDI: ffff8f020cb76f3c
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RBP: ffffb4d340fbf6d8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 0000000000000002
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: R10: ffff8f020cb76000 R11: ffff8f020cb74000 R12: ffff8f020ef43800
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: R13: 0000000000000002 R14: ffff8f020927f800 R15: 0000000000000003
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: FS:  00007fde490f7880(0000) GS:ffff8f111f900000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: CR2: 00007fde4864c160 CR3: 0000000108c7e005 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: Call Trace:
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  <TASK>
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  skl_commit_modeset_enables+0x10b/0x550 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x4af/0x1180 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? intel_atomic_commit_ready+0x4d/0x54 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? __i915_sw_fence_complete+0x111/0x1c0 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  intel_atomic_commit+0x31a/0x390 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  drm_atomic_commit+0x47/0x50 [drm]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  intel_modeset_init+0x1f5/0x240 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  i915_driver_probe+0x1e8/0x3f0 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? mutex_lock+0x13/0x40
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  i915_pci_probe+0x5a/0x140 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  local_pci_probe+0x48/0x80
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  pci_device_probe+0x10f/0x1c0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  really_probe+0x1dc/0x440
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  driver_probe_device+0xf0/0x160
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  device_driver_attach+0x5d/0x70
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  __driver_attach+0xb2/0x140
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? device_driver_attach+0x70/0x70
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  bus_add_driver+0x152/0x1f0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  driver_register+0x74/0xd0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  __pci_register_driver+0x57/0x60
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  i915_init+0x66/0x86 [i915]
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? 0xffffffffc0c99000
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1d0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? __cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x37c/0x440
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  do_init_module+0x62/0x260
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  load_module+0x125d/0x1440
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x61/0xb0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? fput+0x13/0x20
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? ksys_mmap_pgoff+0x13e/0x270
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3d/0x1c0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? __x64_sys_mmap+0x33/0x40
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? __x64_sys_newfstat+0x16/0x20
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fde4967989d
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05>
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffef5b897b8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055f4a7edfb40 RCX: 00007fde4967989d
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fde49556ded RDI: 0000000000000016
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: R10: 0000000000000016 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007fde49556ded
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000055f4a7ee7b50 R15: 000055f4a7edfb40
Feb 04 11:00:14 europa kernel:  </TASK>
Feb 04 11:00:42 europa kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 53s! [systemd-udevd:590]
```

After the recent upgrade to Ubuntu kernel 5.13.0-27-generic my system hangs on boot at the splash screen. I can only get it to boot by adding nomodeset to the grub BOOT_IMAGE command line. I am using the onboard Intel video support of my mother board, i.e., no video display card. After boot with nomodeset my two display screens are stuck at a 1024x768 resolution with both monitors showing identical video. There are no options for changing the display under Display Settings from the desktop.

My current work-around is to revert to the 5.11.0-27-generic kernel where everything works as normal. I have two joined displays working at 1920x1080 resolution.

I would like to be able to fix this issue so I can be able to upgrade to new kernels as they are made available by Ubuntu.

Here are the specifics for my system:

Mother Board: ASRock Z590 Steel Legend WiFi 6E

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8a (rev 04)

lsmod | grep "kms\|drm"

drm_kms_helper        253952  1 i915
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   557056  2 drm_kms_helper,i915

find /dev -group video
/dev/media0
/dev/video1
/dev/video0
/dev/fb0

cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic root=UUID=6d313b91-e8fe-49a1-8efa-c76639b02be9 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 nomodeset

cat /etc/modeprobe.d/*kms*
nothing

ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf
nothing

glxinfo | grep -i "Vendor|rendering"
not installed

grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    20.170] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    20.173] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    20.173] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    20.173] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    20.174] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    20.174] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    20.174] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    20.234] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
```

I think the recent kernel upgrade is somehow not correctly configuring my video.

Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Thanks for any help and guidance you can provide.

Comment: I had also problems with the 5.13.0-27-generic kernel. I returned previous kernel.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one!

Comment: I finally figured out how to fix the formatting on the command outputs :)

Comment: The new kernel is absolutely horrible - I get TV static display after closing the lid, no 
HDMI signal is received from the laptop and neither restart nor shutdown work ("reached target reboot" and then nothing).
I have spent the whole day troubleshooting and two reinstalls laters I figured I will perhaps revert back. Did the trick I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

My system now boots just fine and even the WiFi is working! I decided to try adding a GPU to the system and installed an MSI RX6800. Interestingly the computer would not complete POST with the new GPU until I reset the CMOS memory. After that everything worked fine and I am now running the 5.13.0-37 kernel. I suspect, but have not yet confirmed, needing to reset CMOS memory was the issue all along; especially since I upgraded the BIOS while trouble shooting. Just didn't realize it was necessary. So the issue is closed as far as I'm concerned.